# Долгий отклик команды Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Как выяснить причину зависающих команд Nginx?

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Система VDS: ubuntu 16.04, Nginx 1.10, PHP 7, MySQL 5.7.

Первые часы после настройки сервера всё хорошо, но через пару часов команды nginx подвисают на 5 секунд.

Comment: error.log смотрели? Время ответа в access.log взято? Обращение доходит до php-fpm? Если да, проблема в ваших скриптах и ресурсах к которым они обращаются.

Comment: Смотрел, ошибок нет. В access.log одна строка подключения к сайту, но команды на сервере производил после. То есть на момент команд, всё пусто. Не совсем понимаю какую связь имеет скрипт сайта к задержке команды sudo systemctl restart nginx. У меня есть аналогичный сервер, где всё с теми же настройками, если нужно покажу. Отличие в двух вещах, второй сервер хостинг поменял виртуализацию и изменил ядро ubuntu. Второе это домен был слишком длинный и я включил server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; в etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: Есть ли способ увидеть причину задержки? А то сейчас 13 сек.